# Update an html table from a session variable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I'm fairly new to JSP, jQuery and AJAX.  I have a JSP that uses a table that is populated based on values in a List variable in session.  Code here:

```
<table id="someData" class="display" width="95%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach var="var" items="${sessionVar}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${var.ID}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${var.name}" /></td>
<td><c:if test="${var.gender=='M'}">
<c:out value="Male" />
</c:if> <c:if test="${var.dispositionCD=='F'}">
<c:out value="Female" />
</c:if>
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I call the controller using .ajax and that may result in changes to the sessionVar variable.  Additional people could be added, some could be removed, some names may change, or there could be no changes at all.  The controller would just refresh the List variable that is in session.  Here is my ajax call that runs when the user enters some data and presses a button:

```
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : urlText,
            data : 'testdata',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data,textStatus) {
                $('#errormessage').text(data);
            },
            error : function() {
                $("#errormessage").text("Error while processing request..Please try again");
            }
        });
```

So once the List variable in session is updated, how do I update the data in the html table?  I've been working on JSP and jQuery for about a month so go easy on me if this seems amateur hour.  :)

Comment: I'm no expert in JSP but the basic problem I see is that your initial rendering is done on the server-side, and yet you want to update the table on the client-side, without a page refresh, is that correct?  It would be simpler if all rendering was _either_ server-side _or_ client-side, not both.

Comment: If I'm correct and you want to update the table with Javascript, can you post a sample of the AJAX response?

Comment: For the initial render, the controller is using request.getSession("false").setAttribute("sessionVar", listOfPeopleToShow).  Then, on the JSP, I'm using the c taglib to iterate through the list and populate the table.  It's really client side but using the list placed into session on the server.  Now what I'm trying to do is call the controller, run a function that may or may not update the data and read the data into a new ArrayList, place it in session, return from the ajax call and, in the 'success' function, update the table since its data could have changed.

Comment: Ok, well I don't see how it could be client-side at all.  Session variables are not accessible client-side (unless you use a workaround to write the session variable into a JS variable at run-time but that's still a server-side operation).  The JSP taglibs are server-side components.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/3HGFN/

HTML:

```
<p id="errormessage"></p>
<table id="someData" class="display" width="95%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jane Doe</td>
            <td>Female</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="callAjax">Call the AJAX</button>
```

JS:

```
// We will use MockJAX to simulate an AJAX response - http://code.appendto.com/plugins/jquery-mockjax.
// This is only for illustration purposes, in your real app you would have a working controller.

$.mockjax({
    url: '/people/list',
    responseTime: 750,
    responseText: {
        numHits: 4,
        success: true,
        people: [
            {
                ID: 3,
                name: 'Adam Sapple',
                gender: 'M'
            },
            {
                ID: 4,
                name: 'Bill Board',
                gender: 'M'
            },
            {
                ID: 5,
                name: 'Candy Barr',
                gender: 'F'
            },
            {
                ID: 6,
                name: 'Dan Druff',
                gender: 'M'
            }
        ]
    }
});

$('#callAjax').click(function() {
    // Call the AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : '/people/list',
        data : 'testdata',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data, textStatus) {
            var tbody = $('#someData tbody');

            // clear out the existing table rows
            tbody.empty();

            // iterate through the results
            $.each(data.people, function(idx, person) {
                // create a row for each person
                var row = $('<tr></tr>');
                var genderText = (person.gender == 'M') ? 'Male' : 'Female';

                row.append('<td>' + person.ID + '</td>');
                row.append('<td>' + person.name + '</td>');
                row.append('<td>' + genderText + '</td>');

                tbody.append(row);
            });
        },
        error : function() {
            $("#errormessage").text("Error while processing request..Please try again");
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, I've updated the code.  Basically, you make the AJAX call as before but instead of dynamically creating a new table on success, you reload the page on success.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : '/people/list',
    data : 'testdata',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data, textStatus) {
        // reload page with force reload flag (force reload may not be necessary, try it without)
        location.reload(true);
    },
    error : function() {
        $("#errormessage").text("Error while processing request..Please try again");
    }
});
```

Comment: One thing.  data that is being returned is a boolean to state whether the function was successful. "The function" is in the controller and it could be any edit to the person table.  Once the person table is updated, the sessionVar variable is set as follows in the controller:      request.getSession("false").setAttribute("sessionVar", ListOfPeopleToShow);

Comment: The point there is that sessionVar is not passed back in the ajax call.  That call passes a boolean which I need to perform other tasks - show and hide controls namely.

Comment: Well it sounds to me like you can't do the table update on the client-side at all because you have no access to the data.  Since you need to refresh the page, I would just have a success handler on your $.ajax() call and use that to reload the page, which is already set up to read the current session variable and build a table of people.